Ant Build Illegal character in path only newer versions of Eclipse
When I try to Ant Build (compile java sources), in the old version of Eclipse Neon it works like a charm, but when I try do the same in any newer version of Eclipse, I Always got this error:
compile:
    [javac] Compiling 2098 source files to C:\APPs\eclipse2024\workspace\SR-2024\build\bin
    [javac] error: error reading C:\APPs\eclipse2024\workspace\SR-2024\dist\libs\mmore.jar; java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 61: file:/C:/APPs/eclipse2024/workspace/SR-2024/dist/libs/${manifest.libs}
    [javac] warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 8

BUILD FAILED

This file mmore.jar is a lib and I don't have access to the sources.
The java version for this sources, it's java 8.
I just want's to use a newer version of Eclipse, but can't because of this. I already tried to find information about this error, but anything of that I try, doesn't solve!

Share the ant.xml file. What is the value of ${manifest.libs}?

It seems ${manifest.libs} has not been resolved, otherwise the resolved path would be shown in the error message.

In neon version, it compiles like a charm. Any newer version, not! There is no variable like this in my build.xml file, nothing about ${manifest.libs}. This is de line from xml, when I click in error message, open this line!   . Also, it shows, error reading... mmore.jar (it is a lib file)

Possibly a difference between Ant 1.9 used by Eclipse Neon and Ant 1.10 used by current Eclipse. I also came across a very similar issue here even down to a similar jar name. What is this ''mmore.jar"?
